# Problem loading Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have just installed ubuntu 16:04 from an image disc, all went well until I was requested to re start my Toshiba Satelite Pro laptop. I entered my security key and password and then got a purple screen with 16:04 LTS displayed in the bottom left hand corner, and nothing else other than a flashing error message which I can't read. I did however manage to click continue but nothing has happened. My hard drive indicator light is flashing but nothing else. Please bear in mind that I am a complete novice and have just switched from Windows. Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Geoff

Comment: Did you disable secure boot from bios? This is known to cause login issues  on certain machines, mostly with nvidia but disable it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried disabling secure boot as you suggested but no joy. The flashing error message says something about a hardware error but thanks to it moving around the screen as it flashes it isn't possible to read it in full. Regards Geoff